# protocol_version exception while registering user on hyperledger fabric ca using fabric java sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to register user using fabric java sdk (1.0.1). I am getting following exception "protocol_version" while registering user.

[image]

Any pointer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using Liberty so I'll assume you are also using the IBM JDK/JRE.  In that case, you need to the following properties:

```
-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true   -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Thank You Gari Singh. 

We are using Websphere. However; Its working fine on our dev server, but we are getting exception in our SIT server where all configuration are same. 

Locally, We are using liberty where its also working fine.

Comment: Kindly also let me know where I need to provide properties. In websphere or in java program?

Comment: typically you supply these as command line arguments to the JVM when you start it up

Comment: Yes, It worked. I added properties into websphere server itself. 

Thanks a lot :)